# What to compile as a library?

Tags: c++, libraries

I've lost my head just a little trying to reason the most effective means of compiling a c++ project. I stick to more managed languages like Java so the CMake file is a bit obtuse to me.

My main problem is what do I compile as a library and what do I just compile together? I have a main function in my program with various over classes in different files with headers. What is the most normal way of handling these files together? Should I compile the main function separate from the classes then link them or should they be a shared library even though it is a bit small for a library?

Mainly I am looking just for general guidelines of what should be compiled together, what should simply be linked, and someone to more clearly explain the norms/best practices of how this all works.

I understand that the compiler needs to convert the Header and Source files to object files and then combines them together as a binary. I am just confused at what should go into the binary.

Comment: If there are some methods which is required by other processes as well then its better to put them in a library. If you want to deploy the single binary only, then make the library static but this will increase the binary size.

Comment: In doubt: don't use a library at all. When the project grows, you will learn when to split the code into libraries and binaries.

Comment: Use a library in pretty much the same cases as you'd use a non executable jar in Java.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the code for only one executable you can just link all object files together. Libraries are useful if you need the same functions/object files in different executables.

Of course the bigger a project gets you could also use sub projects which output libraries and then link the main project files and the sub project libraries together.